# Can't delete data in sql database [Angularjs]

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete simple one row data from sql db but it fail. 
[image]

The problem is

```
Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/middlework/administration/dash.php</b> on line <b>225</b><br />
DELETE FROM `cafe` WHERE cafe_id=;Error
```

as you can see [WHERE cafe_id=;] has no value, it sent "" to php file then php can not do their job.

Here are my codes:

```
     $scope.deleteData = function (cafe_id) {
 var path = $scope.path + '?n=' + $scope.table + '&id="' + cafe_id + '"&action=delete' + '&app=true';

            $http.get(path)
                .then(function (response) {
                    //First function handles success
                    // $scope.getData();
                }, function (response) {
                    //Second function handles error
                    $scope.content = "Something went wrong";
                });
        } 



$scope.getData = function () {

            $scope.table = "cafe";

            var path = $scope.path + '?n=' + $scope.table + '&app=true';

            $http.get(path)
                .then(function (response) {
                    //First function handles success
                    $scope.content = response.data;
                    $scope.update = false;
                    $scope.reset();
                }, function (response) {
                    //Second function handles error
                    $scope.content = "Something went wrong";
                });
        }
```

html part

```
<table  method="post" border="1" ng-init="getData();">
<tr ng-repeat="x in content">
  <td>{{x.cafe_id}}</td>
  <td>{{x.Username}}</td>
  <td>{{x.CafeName}}</td>
  <td><button ng-click="editData(x.id)" >Edit</button></td>
  <td><button ng-click="deleteData(x.cafe_id)" >Del</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I do not know your template system but wathing your previous code there should be `deleteData({{x.cafe_id}})`

Comment: @nospor Thanks, I put {{ }} and then I press delete button, it do nothing now.

Comment: Hi! First of all check if the content of response.data.cafe_id you are receiving is not null. Print it with console.log

Comment: @LuizEduardodeChristo Hello ! I did it console.log(response.data.cafe_id); It has no value.

Comment: If you do the same with Username and Cafename does it shows any output?

Comment: Have you initialized 'content' at the beginning of your controller? (e.g): $scope.content = {};

Comment: look in browser dev tools network and see what is actually in the url. If it is as expected then the problem is in your php

Comment: Thanks for all your support ! I fix it by using post method for delete data and create php file with delete sql command, it works fine as I wanted !